# Blank pages for front and back end in EE 1.x

Tags: ee1, blank-screen

I'm trying to recreate an EE1 site locally on my Mac with MAMP and am getting blank pages on both front end and back end after logging in (can see login page OK before logging in though).

I've checked error logs and the only error that's coming up is *Unable to parse XML data*.

DB credentials are correct because if I change them I get the 'can't connect to the db' error message.

I've manually emptied cache folders and have tried changing PHP versions.

Any other steps I can take to figure out what's going on?

Comment: You checked the PHP error logs directly? Do you have EE set to show errors? I think you can do this in config on EE1... If not, you can remove the code from index.php that manages the conditional and force errors. Where exactly are you seeing the "Unable to parse XML data" error?

Comment: I'd suggest increasing PHP memory allotment to a high number to eliminate that.

Comment: EE is set to show errors. Memory shouldn't be an issue as it's on my Mac, so no limit. The XML error is showing up in the PHP error log.

Comment: I feel your errors aren't showing still... White screen is pretty much always a suppressed error. Can you check your index.php file and remove the conditional that checks if you should see errors or not... replacing with error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set( 'display_errors','1'); should get get them showing.

Comment: Also, are you saying that your php.ini file is set to not have a PHP memory limit?

Comment: index.php already has what you've added and there was no php.ini. Adding one with a really high memory limit doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience a white screen is always a suppressed PHP error. If you can't get the error to show, something is still suppressing it.

Instead of going back and forth with comments, we jumped on Skype. In this case, disabling extensions in the config.php file got the PHP error to show up on the screen. This is an EE1 site so we used:

```
$conf['allow_extensions'] = "n";
```

It turns out a Cartthrob directory was missing and was throwing a fatal PHP error.

My theory on why php errors continued to be suppressed even when forcing them to show in the index.php file is that one of the extensions was disabling them afterwards. This explains why they weren't showing on screen or in the php log file until extensions were disabled.

Comment: This answer is confusing.  Did you solve this interactively through chat? (how else did Cartthrob come in?)  Could you expand your answer so it is clearer what the solution is?